# Proguard does not actually keep my class (simple) name, what's the cause?

Tags: java, proguard

When I put the following "keep" rule in my proguard configuration:

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class ** implements com.my.package.MyInterfaceName { <fields>; }
```

At first, it seems that all my classes which implements MyInterfaceName get their class names and fields kept unchanged.

But actually when running, these classes return different simple name with getSimpleName().

Take this for example:

```
public class Foo {
    public enum Bar implements MyInterfaceName { X, Y, Z }
}
```

`X.getClass().getSimpleName()` returns `Foo$Bar` instead of only `Bar` which is returned without being processed by proguard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner classes are just like other classes. ProGuard treats them as such, e.g. when obfuscating their names. If you want to preserve the nested structures, you have to preserve the relevant optional attribute:

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```

Comment: I just want to obfuscate my classes. Please suggest me how to?

Answer (score 0):

Proguard is being very aggressive and erasing more information than needed. Luckily the full name doesn't change thanks to your configuration line but not good news for the simple name. For full handling of enums (they have some magical methods also that need to be kept) you should consult the `Processing enumeration classes` section at http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html

> If your application, applet, servlet, library, etc., contains
>   enumeration classes, you'll have to preserve some special methods.
>   Enumerations were introduced in Java 5. The java compiler translates
>   enumerations into classes with a special structure. Notably, the
>   classes contain implementations of some static methods that the
>   run-time environment accesses by introspection (Isn't that just grand?
>   Introspection is the self-modifying code of a new generation). You
>   have to specify these explicitly, to make sure they aren't removed or
>   obfuscated:

```
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

Comment: After some tests, I'm afraid this does not solve my problem. But the other solution provided by Eric Lafortune does work.